# time difference in python in mod_wsgi

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

I hav used the following code to display a result and time elapsed to find out the result in mod_wsgi.But watever i try i always get the elapsed time as 0 even though i rounded the time to nanoseconds. What do i do now to calculate the difference?

```
#!D:/Python27/python

from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from cgi import parse_qs, escape
import time
import datetime

html = """
<html>
<body>
  <h2>Sum of first n factorials</h2>
   <form method="get" action="Sec1q10.py">
      Number :<input type="text" name="t1">
<br> <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
   <br>
   Result:%s<br>
   Now:%s<br>
   End:%s<br>
   Time:%s
   </body>
</html>"""

def application(environ, start_response):
 d=parse_qs(environ['QUERY_STRING'])
 now = int(round(time.time()*1000000))
 n=d.get('t1',[''])[0]
 i=1
 p=1
 s=0
 while (i<=int(n)):
  p = p*i
  s =s+p
  i = i+1 
 end= int(round(time.time()*1000000))
 diff=end-now
 status = '200 OK'
 output = html % (s or 'Empty',now or 'Empty',end or 'Empty',diff or 'Empty') 

 response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
 start_response(status, response_headers)

 return [output]
```

and the output it shows is if i entered a number 4:

```
Result:33
Now:1346520500489000
End:1346520500489000
Time:Empty
```

wat else can i use to find out the time elapsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time.time()` does not have infinite resolution -- the operation that you're testing takes next to no time at all. Try using a much larger `n`, or repeating the loop a large fixed number of times (e.g, a thousand) and dividing the result by the number of times you repeated it.